Kubuntu window from the 2nd monitor gone after minimized
When windows are minimized, they can be resumed by clicking the small icon from the task bar. However,
In Kubuntu 22.04, when my windows are minimized from the 2nd monitor, I just cannot find them any more in popup icons from the task bar, and cannot easily resume them. In fact, right after I moved them to the 2nd monitor, the popup icons are gone:

I have actually two more Konsole windows on the 2nd monitor.
The Konsole windows just just for illustration purpose. The real pain in the chrome windows, which I have and minimize a lot.
